# How make create all possible lists of twelve elements?

Tags: combinatorics

How can I create all possible lists of twelve elements when each element can be -1 or 1. That is, 2^12 different lists.

Comment: You are looking for all 12-tuples of $\{-1, 1\}$. Tuples is of course the the keyword to look up in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples):

```
res = Tuples[{-1,1}, 12];
% //Length
res[[;;10]]
```

> 4096
>
> {{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, \
>   -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
>     1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 
>     1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
>     1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 
>     1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 
>     1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 
>     1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
>     1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1}}